# How to generate two random numbers, X and Y, and make sure they are never repeated?

Tags: c#, random

Ok, so I am writing a Minesweeper app in WinForms. This is my first C# app so it has been a huge learning process. I want to randomly generate two numbers to put into two separate arrays, mineX & mineY. These two arrays are the coordinates for where all the mines are going to be placed on the board.

Here is the issue, I want to make sure that when it randomly generates these numbers, that X,Y will never be the same. I've done the research and know how to generate a single number and make each one unique. My issue is I want the combination of two random numbers to be unique.

Here is my code for the placeMines method.

```
    private void placeMines()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < MINE_COUNT; i++)
        {               
                bombX[i] = rnd.Next(0, BOARD_X);
                bombY[i] = rnd.Next(0, BOARD_Y)'
        }
    }
```

This seems to be a simple issue to resolve, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Do you mean the combination of X,Y have to be unique, or that as soon as X=2 have been picked, no other X can be 2?

Comment: Right, the combination of the two. X may in fact equal two multiple times, but the corresponding Y has to be different.

Comment: If they cannot repeat, then you do not want random numbers. So don't use a random number generator!

Comment: Important to recognize a *pattern* when you need to solve a problem like this.  You don't want a collection of random values, you want a random *order* of fixed values.  Called a *shuffle*, named for its strong resemblance to shuffling a deck of cards.  The standard algorithm for a shuffle is called Fisher Yates, named for the two statisticians that solved it in 1938.  You'll get massive amounts of Google hits when you query "c# random shuffle" or "c# fisher yates".  11 thousand of them for just this web site, we try to not add more :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a list of possible mine positions.
2. Choose a random item from the list, remove the item.
3. Repeat 2 until there're enough mines.

Sample code:

```
const int BOARD_X = 10;
const int BOARD_Y = 6;
const int MINE_COUNT = 30;

List<int> positions = Enumerable.Range(0, BOARD_X * BOARD_Y).ToList();
var rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < MINE_COUNT; i++) {
    int index = rnd.Next(positions.Count);
    int pos = positions[index];
    positions.RemoveAt(index);
    int x = pos % BOARD_X, y = pos / BOARD_X;
    Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1})", x, y);
}
```

NOTE: If the number of positions is big, you can optimize algorithm for space by using bit vectors. I'll leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense. I have yet to learn about lists so I was under the impression I had no way of comparing a pair of integers  as a whole without converting to a string (intX+","+intY) and then comparing strings. Appreciate it.

Comment: @user3922214 If you don't want encoding of two integers in one integer like this (for readability, for example), you can use tuples (see another answer), custom types, or find an appropriate type from .NET framework (there're point classes in WinForms, WPF, XNA).

Answer (score 3):

Generate all positions (let it be struct with two int fields x, y) in array and shuffle this array.

```
Random _rand = new Random();
Position[] allPositions = GenerateAllPositions();

for (int i=allPositions.Length-1; i>=1; i--)
{
     int j = _rand.Next(0, i+1);
     // now swap
     Position tempPosition = allPositions[i];
     allPositions[i] = allPositions[j];
     allPositions[j] = tempPosition;
}
```

Now you can have temp int variable `lastQueriedPositionIndex = 0`, increase it by one when you pick any position. If `lastQueriedPositionIndex == allPositions.Length` make `lastQueriedPositionIndex=0` and invoke this "swap" routine again. This is `O(n)` worst case solution instead of `O(n^2)` solution proposed by Athari - however in small board dimensions you won't see any diffrence.

Comment: You invoke random number generation for every position. I suspect this can be slow due to multipler which is hidden by O notation. I don't think there's a clear winner.

Comment: @Athari The random number generation is very fast, and shuffeling the list like this (this is a [fisher yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)) does not take very many resources at all. In fact your solution is the slow one because every time you remove a element you need to copy every item. So this one would be O(2N) reads, and your solution of removing the items would be O(N^2) reads.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Measured. This method is roughly 5–10 times faster when proportion of mines is realistic (15% in classic MS Minesweeper on normal difficulty). My method can be faster when proportion is very low, but it's hardly playable.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain A minor nit to pick - O(2N) is O(N).